# (Windows 10) Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Understood that is an often asked question, but I have already set my environment and stuff. (Pic attached). Running Windows 10 requires Pyspark for the course module. Please do help...

Error message after running:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark-master","local").getOrCreate()
```

---

Here is the Traceback:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-12e393ff7f76> in <module>
      1 import pyspark
      2 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 3 spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark-master","local").getOrCreate()

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    171                     for key, value in self._options.items():
    172                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
--> 173                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    174                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
    175                     for key, value in self._options.items():

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    365         with SparkContext._lock:
    366             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 367                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    368             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    369 

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    131                     " note this option will be removed in Spark 3.0")
    132 
--> 133         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    134         try:
    135             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    314         with SparkContext._lock:
    315             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 316                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    317                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    318 

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf)
     44     :return: a JVM gateway
     45     """
---> 46     return _launch_gateway(conf)
     47 
     48 

C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py in _launch_gateway(conf, insecure)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

---

​[image: Environment settings]

Comment: did you happen to solve the problem?